# Zipf's vs Self-similar: are they really the same

Tags: distributions, zipf

Recently I ran into a test using both zipf's and self-similar generated datasets. I followed the description from Jim Gray's paper on generating such datasets ([Quickly Generating Billon-Record Synthetic Databases](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CEIQFjAB&url=http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=68246&ei=PjElUdFR58mKApvNgOAG&usg=AFQjCNHku_13V2vvn_X2YvaTcXNw00AeJw&sig2=asoGxjsGyUyOXMroIz9t0w&bvm=bv.42661473,d.cGE)). In that paper it mentions:

> It is commonly thought that self-similarity and the Zipf distribution are the same, or at least close. This misconception ... In particular, other statistics can yield very different results for the self-similar and Zipf distributions.

So my question is, from a statistic point of view, what is the actual difference between these two distributions intuitively? I am not a statistician, but (probably wrong) my thought is that they are all some power-law shaped distribution...

Just clarify: when I am talking about "the same", I am meaning that there is a (mathematic or statistic) way to bridge these two distributions... or one can be converted (mapped) into another...